# How to separate string and URLs into different lists in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to split the lists which contain a string and URL into different lists. I have tried some solutions, yet it still cannot be addressed.

I used to apply a package called `URLExtract` for the list, yet it returns a none to me.

```
print(results)

[['1.', 'Oases | Define Oases at Dictionary.com\n  https://www.dictionary.com/browse/oases'],  
['2.', 'oases - Yahoo Dictionary\n  https://dictionary.yahoo.com/dictionary?p=oases'], 
['3.', 'OASES Cambridge Dictionary\n  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/zht/%E8%A9%9E%E5%85%B8/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E/oases'], 
['4.', 'Oases - Wikipedia\n  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oasis'], 
['5.', 'Oases definition and meaning | Collins English Dictionary\n  https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/oases'], 
['6.', 'OASES - YouTube\n  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5gJVgIZgYQ'], 
['7.', 'Oases - definition of oases by The Free Dictionary\n  https://www.thefreedictionary.com/oases'], 
['8.', 'Oases – Correct Spelling – Grammarist\n  https://grammarist.com/spelling/oases/'], 
['9.', 'Online Tutoring Management & Scheduling Software | Oases\n  https://oasesonline.com/'], 
['10.', 'OASES – Log in\n  https://oases.wageningenacademic.com/']]
```

*Expected outputs*

```
print(intro)
1. Oases | Define Oases at Dictionary.com
2. oases - Yahoo Dictionary
3. OASES Cambridge Dictionary
4. Oases - Wikipedia
...
10. OASES – Log in

print(urls)
https://www.dictionary.com/browse/oases
https://dictionary.yahoo.com/dictionary?p=oases
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/zht/%E8%A9%9E%E5%85%B8/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E/oases
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oasis
...
https://oases.wageningenacademic.com/
```

Comment: What is this package `UrlExtract`? Can you share the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.splitlines()` in your case

**Ex:**

```
data = [['1.', 'Oases | Define Oases at Dictionary.com\n  https://www.dictionary.com/browse/oases'],  
['2.', 'oases - Yahoo Dictionary\n  https://dictionary.yahoo.com/dictionary?p=oases'], 
['3.', 'OASES Cambridge Dictionary\n  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/zht/%E8%A9%9E%E5%85%B8/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E/oases'], 
['4.', 'Oases - Wikipedia\n  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oasis'], 
['5.', 'Oases definition and meaning | Collins English Dictionary\n  https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/oases'], 
['6.', 'OASES - YouTube\n  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5gJVgIZgYQ'], 
['7.', 'Oases - definition of oases by The Free Dictionary\n  https://www.thefreedictionary.com/oases'], 
['8.', 'Oases – Correct Spelling – Grammarist\n  https://grammarist.com/spelling/oases/'], 
['9.', 'Online Tutoring Management & Scheduling Software | Oases\n  https://oasesonline.com/'], 
['10.', 'OASES – Log in\n  https://oases.wageningenacademic.com/']]

intros = []
urls = []
for i in data:
    intro, url = i[1].splitlines()
    intros.append(intro.strip())
    urls.append(url.strip())

print(intros)
print(urls)
```

**Output:**

```
['Oases | Define Oases at Dictionary.com',
 'oases - Yahoo Dictionary',
 'OASES Cambridge Dictionary',
 'Oases - Wikipedia',
 'Oases definition and meaning | Collins English Dictionary',
 'OASES - YouTube',
 'Oases - definition of oases by The Free Dictionary',
 'Oases - Correct Spelling - Grammarist',
 'Online Tutoring Management & Scheduling Software | Oases',
 'OASES - Log in']

['https://www.dictionary.com/browse/oases',
 'https://dictionary.yahoo.com/dictionary?p=oases',
 'https://dictionary.cambridge.org/zht/%E8%A9%9E%E5%85%B8/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E/oases',
 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oasis',
 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/oases',
 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5gJVgIZgYQ',
 'https://www.thefreedictionary.com/oases',
 'https://grammarist.com/spelling/oases/',
 'https://oasesonline.com/',
 'https://oases.wageningenacademic.com/']
```

Comment: I am glad to have your reply, which is so so so helpful indeed and it enables me to move on to the next process of my homework. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by looping over the list then splitting the lines (indexing at 1 to only include the part of the list you want):

```
intro = []
urls = []
for entry in results:
  intro_res, url_res = entry[1].split('\n')
  intro.append(intro_res)
  urls.append(url_res.lstrip()) # We lstrip here because you have whitespace
```

Output:

```
['Oases | Define Oases at Dictionary.com',
 'oases - Yahoo Dictionary',
 'OASES Cambridge Dictionary',
 'Oases - Wikipedia',
 'Oases definition and meaning | Collins English Dictionary',
 'OASES - YouTube',
 'Oases - definition of oases by The Free Dictionary',
 'Oases - Correct Spelling - Grammarist',
 'Online Tutoring Management & Scheduling Software | Oases',
 'OASES - Log in']

['https://www.dictionary.com/browse/oases',
 'https://dictionary.yahoo.com/dictionary?p=oases',
 'https://dictionary.cambridge.org/zht/%E8%A9%9E%E5%85%B8/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E/oases',
 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oasis',
 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/oases',
 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5gJVgIZgYQ',
 'https://www.thefreedictionary.com/oases',
 'https://grammarist.com/spelling/oases/',
 'https://oasesonline.com/',
 'https://oases.wageningenacademic.com/']
```

Comment: Thank you very much. What an inspired answer:)

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> data = [
['1.', 'Oases | Define Oases at Dictionary.com\n  https://www.dictionary.com/browse/oases'],  
['2.', 'oases - Yahoo Dictionary\n  https://dictionary.yahoo.com/dictionary?p=oases'], 
['3.', 'OASES Cambridge Dictionary\n  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/zht/%E8%A9%9E%E5%85%B8/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E/oases'], 
['4.', 'Oases - Wikipedia\n  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oasis'], 
['5.', 'Oases definition and meaning | Collins English Dictionary\n  https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/oases'], 
['6.', 'OASES - YouTube\n  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5gJVgIZgYQ'], 
['7.', 'Oases - definition of oases by The Free Dictionary\n  https://www.thefreedictionary.com/oases'], 
['8.', 'Oases – Correct Spelling – Grammarist\n  https://grammarist.com/spelling/oases/'], 
['9.', 'Online Tutoring Management & Scheduling Software | Oases\n  https://oasesonline.com/'], 
['10.', 'OASES – Log in\n  https://oases.wageningenacademic.com/']]
>>>
>>> intro = [i[1].splitlines()[0] for i in data]
>>> urls = [i[1].splitlines()[1].strip() for i in data]
>>>
>>> print(intro)
['Oases | Define Oases at Dictionary.com',
 'oases - Yahoo Dictionary',
 'OASES Cambridge Dictionary',
 'Oases - Wikipedia',
 'Oases definition and meaning | Collins English Dictionary',
 'OASES - YouTube',
 'Oases - definition of oases by The Free Dictionary',
 'Oases – Correct Spelling – Grammarist',
 'Online Tutoring Management & Scheduling Software | Oases',
 'OASES – Log in']
>>>
>>> print(urls)
['https://www.dictionary.com/browse/oases',
 'https://dictionary.yahoo.com/dictionary?p=oases',
 'https://dictionary.cambridge.org/zht/%E8%A9%9E%E5%85%B8/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E/oases',
 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oasis',
 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/oases',
 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5gJVgIZgYQ',
 'https://www.thefreedictionary.com/oases',
 'https://grammarist.com/spelling/oases/',
 'https://oasesonline.com/',
 'https://oases.wageningenacademic.com/']
```

I did this using [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score -1):

Using `splitlines` to  split the URL and its relevant piece of information should solve the problem here:

```
info = []
urls = []
for entry in data: 
    url_info = entry[1].splitlines()    # Split info and URL
    info.append('{} {}'.format(entry[0], url_info[0]))      # Create a new list of info  
    urls.append(url_info[1].strip())    # Create a new list of urls

print(info)
print(urls)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help:))